# OSMdroid custom offline xyzTiles?

Tags: android, qgis, osmdroid

Suppose you made a map in QGIS then used the tool "Generate XYZ Tiles" to create a directory or MBTiles file of XYZ Map Tiles. Is it possible to display that on an Android phone using OSMdroid?
If it isn't, is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about osmdroid, but it looks it's possible. For sure you can use tiles in OSMAnd (in a bit weird way, I have to admit, as overlay). OruxMaps supports tiles as well. You can check MOBAC (https://sourceforge.net/projects/mobac/) for possible outputs / programs which accepts the tiles.

For mbtiles with mobac, please see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/294022/open-a-local-mbtiles-map-in-mobile-atlas-creator-mobac

Comment: I managed to make it work somewhat in OSMAnd. First i imported my tiles in MOBAC, then generated an Atlas in OSMAnd sqlite format and moved that to the /tiles directory on my phone. Now if I change map source in the App to my sqlite file I can see my map. It is however really blurry and it seems that not all zoom levels are shown. 
MOBAC also has a few osmdroid formats but no matter which one I used I couldnt get it to display my map there.

Comment: Good to know. Maybe try with deeper zoom level/resolution on QGIS side.

Comment: In QGIS I used zoom levels 13 to 20 with 256p resolution.  MOBAC displays all levels without issue but in OSMAnd it looks like only levels <= 18 are shown.
I'd rather not go deeper with resolution or zoom level as I already have 200,000+ tiles at around 3GB total and rendering takes a long, long time.